# Which salts give the sodium carbonate bead test?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis, salt

Apart from the borax and the phosphate bead tests, there's also this one.

It's  done by heating the white bead of sodium carbonate and the salt with potassium nitrate; green and yellow colours indicate the presence of manganese and chromium respectively.

I've only seen these two examples for this test. Are there any more?